# Not be able to sent request to the Thunder Client from visual studio

Tags: thunderclient

I am currently grappling with an issue while using Thunder Client in Visual Studio Code, and I am seeking your expertise to navigate through it. The problem arises when attempting to send a request to my database using Thunder Client, as I consistently encounter the error message: "Connection was forcibly closed by a peer."

This issue is proving to be a roadblock in my database interactions, and I am reaching out for assistance in understanding and resolving it. My current setup includes Visual Studio Code, Thunder Client extension version v2.17.0 - (2024-01-03), and I am working with MongoDB.

Despite extensive troubleshooting, including checking server logs, ensuring the database server is operational, and reviewing firewall and network settings, the problem persists. I am uncertain about the root cause and am seeking insights, experiences, or potential solutions from the community.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or possesses expertise in Thunder Client troubleshooting, your guidance would be invaluable. Additionally, if there are specific steps or configurations I may have overlooked, I am eager to learn.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1GZE.png)

I want to know how to fix this issue

Comment: Try these solutions - https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/common-issues.md